# Canvas Maze character's distance from walls

Tags: javascript, algorithm, canvas

I am working on a 2D maze game with a torch effect in canvas without the use of any raytracing. Everything is working great, however the torch effect's algorithm is causing immense lags in several browsers and computers. (It is weird as well, that the game runs smoother on older computers. The funniest is, IExplorer runs the game without any lags, while mozzila dies on every move..)

My general idea for solving this problem was, to get how far the character is from the walls (4 functions) and make the rest of the maze grey.

Here is an example with the Northern wall detection:
http://webprogramozas.inf.elte.hu/~ce0ta3/beadando/maze_example.png

And an example how it is working at the moment and what I would like to achieve without lag issues.
http://webprogramozas.inf.elte.hu/~ce0ta3/beadando/ce0ta3_html5_maze.html

As I mentioned above, the algorithm that tracks the character's distance from the walls is causing incredible lags.

```
//Get the character's X,Y position as parameter
function distanceFromNorth (posX,posY)
{
    distNorth = 0;
    var l = false;
    //Start getting charSize x 1 px lines from the character position towards the up, until we reach the max viewDistance or we find a black pixel in the charSize x 1 line.
    for (var i = posY; i > posY - viewDistance && !l; i--)
    {
        var mazeWallData = context.getImageData(posX, i, charSize, 1);
        var data = mazeWallData.data;
        //Check if there are any black pixels in the line
        for (var j = 0; j < 4 * charSize && !l; j += 4)
        {
            l = (data[j] === 0 && data[j + 1] === 0 && data[j + 2] === 0);
        }
        distNorth++;
    }
    return distNorth;
}
```

I am fairly sure, that the ctx.getImageData() is the most costly method in this linear search and if I only requested this method once for a charSize x viewDistance rectangle, and then check for black pixels in that huge array, then the lag could be reduced greatly. However, I still want to keep searching in lines, because finding only one black pixel will return false distNorth value.

I would be grateful if anyone could convert my code into the form I mentioned in the previous paragraph.

Comment: is the image data changing by any chance

Comment: No. And if I call getImageData() method anywhere else, it's working perfectly. Although, in the other cases I either check only one pixel with it, or one line only. (So getImageData does not get called in a loop, anywhere else, only here.) This is why I suspect, that the method is the source of the lag.

Comment: Recomputing posY - viewDistance and 4 * charSize can't be good for performance.  I assume they're loop-invariant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the image data isnt changing then you can precompute all the pixel values that have black pixel. Then use simple binary search on it to get the any black pixels in the given range.

**Algorithm : -**

```
cols[];
rows[];

for(int i=0;i<height;i++) {

 for(int j=0;j<width;j++) {

     if(pixel(j,i)==black) {
        row[i].add(j);
        col[j].add(i);
     }
  }
} 

for query on (x,y) :

distance = binarysearch(col[x],y,y-distance) - y
```